# jquery after method not returning generated element

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following code:

```
var genContent = "<tr><td>please wait!!!</td></tr>";
var outputElement = $("#projectsTable tr:first").after(genContent);
myForm = $(this).find("form");
submitForm(myForm, outputElement);
```

I expect outputElement to be the element generated by the `after` method from jquery, but for some reason outputElement is refering to the table headers.

What do I need to do to get the newly generated element?

Comment: `$("#projectsTable tr:first").after(genContent).end()`

Comment: @adeneo: That doesn't work.  `.after()` returns the same jQuery object, so there's no parent to go up to (that's what `.end()` does).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `after` method inserts element(s) after the current selection, and returns that same current selection. So it does not change the selection. If you need the elements that you want to insert, maybe create a jQuery object of it, and insert that.

```
var genContent = "<tr><td>please wait!!!</td></tr>";
var outputElement = $(genContent);
$("#projectsTable tr:first").after(outputElement);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [`.insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter) if you want `outputElement` to refer to the `tr` element

```
var = "<tr><td>please wait!!!</td></tr>";
var outputElement = $(genContent).insertAfter("#projectsTable tr:first");
myForm = $(this).find("form");
submitForm(myForm, outputElement);
```